# 3D sci-fi animation the team mascot is swallowed by a sky-dwelling monster named Leviathan

Tags: story-identification, animation

A 3D sci-fi animation. A group of friends has a mascot who is swallowed by a sky-dwelling monster named Leviathan. Other people are swallowed too. In the end Leviathan is defeated and the people swallowed by it are saved.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you watch this?  How long was it?  How realistically were the characters rendered?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4):

The computer-animated TV show [*Storm Hawks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Hawks) has an episode called "Leviathan" where a flying air-beast (called "Leviathan," oddly) swallows the team's ship *Condor*, as well as some people.

> When the Condor and Radarr are swallowed by the terra-sized beast known as the Leviathan, the Storm Hawks find themselves unable to fight the beast, forcing them to team up with a reluctant Sky Knight (whose crew and only brother had already been swallowed) to get their home back. Stork, meanwhile, goes into "Sky Shock" after witnessing the Condor being eaten firsthand. With Stork's shock-driven bravery and a replacement ship loaned to them by the Sky Knight, the Storm Hawks are able to get their home back. At the same time, they inadvertently discover how to repel the beast, ensuring that it will never attack any ships again.

Radarr is not the team mascot, he's a full member of the team, but he's small and furry so he *looks* like he might be a mascot.  (He hates that though.)